# Excel: Find intersection of a row and a column

Tags: excel, row, formula

My question is how can I find an intersecting cell of a specific column and row number?

My situation is this: with some calculations I find two cells, lets say **B6** and **E1**. I know that I need a row of the first one and a column of the second one. So I could just use **ROW** and **COLUMN** functions to get the numbers. After that, I need to find an intersecting cell. Which would be **E6** in this example.

I would just use **INDEX(A1:Z100;ROW;COLUMN)** but I don't know the exact area that I'm going to need - it depends on other stuff. I could use something like **A1:XFG65000** but that is way too lame. I could also use a combination of **INDIRECT(ADDRESS())** but I'm pulling data from a closed workbook so **INDIRECT** will not work.

If this would help to know what is this all for - here's a concrete example:
I need to find limits of a section of a sheet that I would work with. I know that it starts from the column **B** and goes all the way down to the last non-empty cell in this column. This range ends with a last column that has any value in **first row**. So to define it - I need to find the intersection of this last column and the last row with values in B column.
I use this array formula to find the last column:

**INDEX(1:1;MAX((1:1<>"")*(COLUMN(1:1))))**

And this array formula to find the last row:

**INDEX(B:B;MAX((B:B<>"")*(ROW(B:B)))**

Last column results in **E1** and last row results in **B6**. Now I need to define my range as **B1:E6**, how can I get **E6** out of this all to put into the resulting formula? I've been thinking for a while now and not being and Excel expert - I couldn't come up with anything. So any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Index/Match combination and use the Match to find the relevant cell. Use one Match() for the row and one Match() for the column.

The index/match function to find the last cell in a sheet where

- column B is the leftmost table column
- row 1 is the topmost table row
- data in column B and in row 1 can be a mix of text and numbers
- there can be empty cells in column B and row 1
- the last populated cell in column B marks the last row of the table
- the last populated cell in row 1 marks the last column of the table

With these premises, the following will return correct results, used in a Sum() with A1 as the starting cell and Index to return the lower right cell of the range:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(1:1048576,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(99^99,B:B,1),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzzz",B:B,1),0)),MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(99^99,1:1,1),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzzz",1:1,1),0))))
```

Since you seem to be on a system with the semicolon as the list delimiter, here is the formula with semicolons:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(1:1048576;MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(99^99;B:B;1);0);IFERROR(MATCH("zzzz";B:B;1);0));MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(99^99;1:1;1);0);IFERROR(MATCH("zzzz";1:1;1);0))))
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a concrete example. I just wanted to be as abstract as possible, as this task - finding intersection of a row and a column could be helpful to others who would google this page.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to return a range for use in another formula, e.g. B1:E6, or do you want to return only E6? If the latter, do you want to return the address or the value of E6? Do you know where the table starts or do you need to find the starting cell?

Comment: disregard the last sentence. It seems that the table starts in B1.  Are the values in row 1 text or numbers? Are the values in column B text or numbers? You may not need an array formula if the values are of the same type. Array formulas across a whole row or a whole column are very resource expensive and will slow down the workbook. If you can define the data type for row 1 and column B, a Match() can be a LOT faster than an array formula.

Comment: I need to find last non-empty cell in B column and last non-empty cell in 1 row. I thought these 2 task would be quite independent of each other. I don't have control over that table as it is automatically generated and sent to me, I'm making a workbook to parse it for the values I need. I need a formula to retrieve E6 to use it in other formula. So I could, say, have SUM(A1:E6) and replace E6 with that formula and it would work. I'm pretty sure data is of a text type in both column B and row 1, can't check now. But there could be empty cells and other "surprises".

Comment: I've edited my answer above with a formua that does what you describe.

Comment: Thank you! This is a useful replacement to an array formula I had. However it's not an answer for an original question of how to find intersection so I will vote it up, but still leave the question open.

Comment: The result of the index ***is*** the intersection of the last non-empty row in column b and the and last non-empty column in row 1. What other intersection do you need?

Comment: Well, if the only way to find an intersection is to search through manually entered huge range with INDEX then I guess yes, that could qualify as an answer. I just thought there could be a way to automate that 1:1048576 range.

Comment: No need to enter that range manually. Just one click on the square above row 1 and to the left of column A. This will select all cells in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

`Offset` would seem to be the way to go

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROW(CELL1)-1,COLUMN(CELL2)-1)
```

(The **-1** is needed because we already have 1 column and 1 row in A1)

in your example, `=OFFSET($A$1,ROW(B6)-1,COLUMN(E1)-1)` would give the value in E6

There is also `ADDRESSS` if you want the location: `=ADDRESS(ROW(B6),COLUMN(E1))` gives the answer **$E$6**

Comment: That would be a solution, but I mentioned in my question that I'm reading a closed workbook and both OFFSET or ADDRESS will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following webpage has a much easier solution, and it seems to work.

https://trumpexcel.com/intersect-operator-in-excel/

For example, in a cell, type simply: =C:C 6:6.  Be sure to include one space between the column designation and the row designation.  The result in your cell will be the value of cell C6.  Of course, you can use more limited ranges, such as =C2:C13 B5:D5 (as shown on the webpage).

As I was searching for the answer to the same basic question, it astounded me that there is no INTERSECT worksheet function in Excel.  There is an INTERSECT feature in VBA (I think), but not a worksheet function.

Anyway, the simple spacing method shown above seems to work, at least in straightforward cases.