# SUMIFS with multiple options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: help]

I need to use SUMIFS function or other excel functions to find the requirement that I need!

For example, I need the value of Cat 1 & Cat 22 so the returning value should be $19,152.

Any advice?

Comment: Yes, show some data of the source and result, but for what you describe sumifs() should work.

Comment: SUMIFS() is looking at rows in a column in the range to match your criteria. Now you are matching values in the column to a string, which will never match of course. What you (seem to) want is to find the intersection of a column and a row. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397142/excel-find-intersection-of-a-row-and-a-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Find intersection of a row and a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397142/excel-find-intersection-of-a-row-and-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use sumifs since you searching for one value row wise and the other value column wise.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F5,(B1:F1="Cat 1")*(A2:A5="Cat 22"))
```

Or if you want to find it with index + match, enter it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter:

```
{=INDEX(B2:F5,MATCH(1,--(A2:A5="Cat 22"),0);MATCH(1,--(B1:F1="Cat 1"),0))}
```

[image]

Comment: If i want to find the sum of Cat 33, Cat 1, Cat 3 which is  $37,720.00(Cat 1)  plus $20,006.00(Cat 3) equal $57,726.00? How do I do so?

Comment: One I can think of now... `{=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F5,(B1:F1="Cat 1")*(A2:A5="Cat 33"))+SUMPRODUCT(B2:F5,(B1:F1="Cat 3")*(A2:A5="Cat 33"))}`.

Comment: Which can be simplified to: `{=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F5;((B1:F1="Cat 1")+(B1:F1="Cat 3"))*(A2:A5="Cat 33"))}`

Comment: why does the SUMPRODUCT need to be entered as an array formula?

Answer (score 1):

If you Name all your rows and columns, you can use simply, for example:

```
=Cat_1 Cat_22
=Cat_2 Cat_44
```

The `space` between the two named ranges is the `Intersect` operator, and so returns the cell at the intersection of the two ranges.

You don't really have to use Name'd ranges (you could use the range references), but it makes visualization of what you are doing easier.

[image]

And if you want to find the sum of multiple intersections, you can just use the addition operator or the Sum function on multiple intersections.

eg:    `=SUM(Cat_1 Cat_33, Cat_3 Cat_33)`